# switching Jpanels 1 Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've been searching and nothing has been simple enough for me.  But for the thing I'm working on I want to make one JFrame in my main method and use different class files for each JPanel.  (This is to keep the information separated and clean). 
Also what's the best way to switch JPanels if I do it in this method?

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
public Main(){
    JFrame intro = new JFrame("FormProgram");
    intro.setSize(800,600);
    intro.setVisible(true);
    intro.setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    intro.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Main();

}
```

Then my basic second class looks like this.

```
public class Page1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{


public JLabel test;

public void Page1(){

    Container cp = intro.getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(null);
    this.test = new JLabel("welcome");
    this.test.setBounds(5,5,300,300);
    cp.add(test);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

> what's the best way to switch JPanels

Use a `CardLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use a CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and a working example.

Comment: I understand CardLayout is pretty common but I can't find out how to separate the layouts to different classes, and it's important for me in this project to have them separate.

Comment: Each child panel can be in a separate class. These panels can use whatever layout manager is approapriate for the layout of each panel. Then in your main class that creates the GUI you create a main panel that uses a CardLayout. Then you create instances of your child panels and add these panels to the panel using the CardLayout.